# codegen "typescript-react-apollo" plugin is redeclaring block-scope variables in generated output

Tags: typescript, next.js, apollo-client, react-apollo, graphql-codegen

I've just started a new project that uses NextJS with [graphql-codegen](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen/plugins/typescript/typescript-react-apollo) to generate my apollo-react types from my api. However, right off the bat it's creating duplicate exported variables and I can't build my project due to the typescript error. Any thoughts on how to prevent codegen from creating these duplicates?

##### codegen.ts

```js
import type { CodegenConfig } from "@graphql-codegen/cli";

const config: CodegenConfig = {
  overwrite: true,
  documents: ["src/**/*.tsx"],
  schema: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT,
  generates: {
    "./src/graphql/__generated__/": {
      preset: "client",
      plugins: ["typescript-react-apollo"],
    },
  },
};
export default config;
```

##### codegen error

```js
// ./src/graphql/__generated__/
...
// creates two 'UserDocument' variables
export const UserDocument = {"kind":"Document","definitions":[{"kind":"OperationDefinition","operation":"query","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"User"},"variableDefinitions":[{"kind":"VariableDefinition","variable":{"kind":"Variable","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"userId"}},"type":{"kind":"NamedType","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"ObjectId"}}}],"selectionSet":{"kind":"SelectionSet","selections":[{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"user"},"arguments":[{"kind":"Argument","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"id"},"value":{"kind":"Variable","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"userId"}}}],"selectionSet":{"kind":"SelectionSet","selections":[{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"id"}},{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"name"}},{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"email"}},{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"image"}},{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"hashedPassword"}},{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"role"}}]}}]}}]} as unknown as DocumentNode<UserQuery, UserQueryVariables>;

export const UserDocument = gql`
    query User($userId: ObjectId) {
  user(id: $userId) {
    id
    name
    email
    image
    hashedPassword
    role
  }
}
    `;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up dumping the `generates: { preset: 'client' }` field and passed in all my own plugins and updated the configuration:

```js
import type { CodegenConfig } from "@graphql-codegen/cli";

const config: CodegenConfig = {
  overwrite: true,
  documents: ["src/**/*.tsx"],
  schema: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT,
  generates: {
    "./src/graphql/__generated__/graphql.ts": {
      plugins: [
        "typescript",
        "typescript-operations",
        "typescript-react-apollo",
      ],
    },
  },
};
export default config;
```

This seems to work.